# How to start a timer on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to get a 2 minutes timer on click of a link.

```html
<a href="javascript:void(1);">Resend code</a>
```

Can anyone help?

Regards,
Bill

Comment: 12000 milliseconds is 12 seconds. You need 2000

Answer (score 2):

```
<button id = "timerButton" onclick = "myTimer()">Resend code</button>
```

javascript code

```
let cTime = 120;
function myTimer(){
  if(cTime == 0){
    document.getElementById("timerButton").innerHTML = "Resend code";
  } else{
    document.getElementById("timerButton").innerHTML = cTime;
    cTime = cTime - 1;
    setTimeout(myTimer, 1000);
  }
}
```

I edit my answer

Comment: No I mean when you click "Resend code" link the text "Resend code" is replaced with "Try another code in 02:00", "Try another code in 01:59", and so on until 0:00 and the Resend code button appears back!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var mins;
var secs;
var interval;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#send-code").click(function() {
    mins = 2;
    secs = 0;
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.attr("disabled", true);
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      if (mins >= 0 && secs >= 0) {
        btn.text("Resend Code in " + pad(mins, 2) + ":" + pad(secs, 2));
        if (secs > 0) {
          secs--;
        } else {
          secs = 59;
          mins--;
        }
        if (mins < 0)
        {
          clearInterval(interval);
          btn.removeAttr("disabled").text("Send Code");
          return true;
        }
      }
      console.log("Mins: " + mins + ", Secs: " + secs);
    }, 1000);
  });
});

function pad(num, size) {
  var s = num + "";
  while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
  return s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="send-code">Send Code</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello you can use `countdown` function and change the time you want in `js-startTimer` function

```js
var interval;

function countdown() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval( function() {
      var timer = $('.js-timeout').html();
      timer = timer.split(':');
      var minutes = timer[0];
      var seconds = timer[1];
      seconds -= 1;
      if (minutes < 0) return;
      else if (seconds < 0 && minutes != 0) {
          minutes -= 1;
          seconds = 59;
      }
      else if (seconds < 10 && length.seconds != 2) seconds = '0' + seconds;

      $('.js-timeout').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);

      if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) clearInterval(interval);
  }, 1000);
}

$('#js-startTimer').click(function () {
  $('.js-timeout').text("2:00");
  countdown();
});
```

```html
<p>2 minutes timer <span class="js-timeout">2:00</span>.</p>

<button id="js-startTimer">Start Countdown</button>
```